# Running Total with subtraction

Tags: r, if-statement, cumsum

I have a data set with closing and opening dates of public schools in California. Available [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/si/ds/pubschls.asp) or `dput()` at the bottom of the question. The data also lists what type of school it is and where it is. I am trying to create a running total column which also takes into account school closings as well as school type.

Here is the solution I've come up with, which basically entails me encoding a lot of different 1's and 0's based on the conditions using `ifelse`:

```
# open charter schools
pubschls$open_chart <-  ifelse(pubschls$Charter=="Y" & is.na(pubschls$ClosedDate)==TRUE, 1, 0)
# open public schools
pubschls$open_pub <- ifelse(pubschls$Charter=="N" & is.na(pubschls$ClosedDate)==TRUE, 1, 0)
# closed charters
pubschls$closed_chart <- ifelse(pubschls$Charter=="Y" & is.na(pubschls$ClosedDate)==FALSE, 1,  0)
# closed public schools 
pubschls$closed_pub <- ifelse(pubschls$Charter=="N" & is.na(pubschls$ClosedDate)==FALSE, 1,  0)
lausd <- filter(pubschls, NCESDist=="0622710")
# count number open during each year
```

Then I subtract the columns from each other to get totals.

```
la_schools_count <- aggregate(lausd[c('open_chart','closed_chart','open_pub','closed_pub')],
 by=list(year(lausd$OpenDate)), sum)

    # find net charters by subtracting closed from open
    la_schools_count$net_chart <- la_schools_count$open_chart - la_schools_count$closed_chart
    # find net public schools by subtracting closed from open
    la_schools_count$net_pub <- la_schools_count$open_pub - la_schools_count$closed_pub
    # add running totals 
    la_schools_count$cum_chart <- cumsum(la_schools_count$net_chart)
    la_schools_count$cum_pub <- cumsum(la_schools_count$net_pub)
    # total totals 
    la_schools_count$total <- la_schools_count$cum_chart + la_schools_count$cum_pub
```

My output looks like this:

```
la_schools_count <- select(la_schools_count, "year", "cum_chart", "cum_pub", "pen_rate", "total")
     year cum_chart cum_pub  pen_rate total
1  1952         1       0 100.00000     1
2  1956         1       1  50.00000     2
3  1969         1       2  33.33333     3
4  1980        55     469  10.49618   524
5  1989        55     470  10.47619   525
6  1990        55     470  10.47619   525
7  1991        55     473  10.41667   528
8  1992        55     476  10.35782   531
9  1993        55     477  10.33835   532
10 1994        56     478  10.48689   534
11 1995        57     478  10.65421   535
12 1996        57     479  10.63433   536
13 1997        58     481  10.76067   539
14 1998        59     480  10.94620   539
15 1999        61     480  11.27542   541
16 2000        61     481  11.25461   542
17 2001        62     482  11.39706   544
18 2002        64     484  11.67883   548
19 2003        73     485  13.08244   558
20 2004        83     496  14.33506   579
21 2005        90     524  14.65798   614
22 2006        96     532  15.28662   628
23 2007        90     534  14.42308   624
24 2008        97     539  15.25157   636
25 2009       108     546  16.51376   654
26 2010       124     566  17.97101   690
27 2011       140     580  19.44444   720
28 2012       144     605  19.22563   749
29 2013       162     609  21.01167   771
30 2014       179     611  22.65823   790
31 2015       195     611  24.19355   806
32 2016       203     614  24.84700   817
33 2017       211     619  25.42169   830
```

I'm just wondering if this could be done in a better way. Like an `apply` statement to all rows based on the conditions?

```
dput:
structure(list(CDSCode = c("19647330100289", "19647330100297", 
"19647330100669", "19647330100677", "19647330100743", "19647330100750"
), OpenDate = structure(c(12324, 12297, 12240, 12299, 12634, 
12310), class = "Date"), ClosedDate = structure(c(NA, 15176, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Charter = c("Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y")), .Names = c("CDSCode", "OpenDate", "ClosedDate", 
"Charter"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is `pen_rate`? You have not explained it yet.

Comment: Yeah. pen_rate isn't super important. It's penetration rate. Basically I took the number of charters and divided by the total. Seems useful but I'm sure there's a better way to show the proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your code and learned what you were doing except `pen_rate`. It seems that `pen_rate` is calculated dividing `cum_chart` by `total`. I download the original data set and did the following. I called the data set `foo`. Whenclosed_pub), I combined `Charter` and `ClosedDate`. I checked if ClosedDate is NA or not, and converted the logical output to numbers (1 = open, 0 = closed). This is how I created the four groups (i.e., open_chart, closed_chart, open_pub, and closed_pub). I guess this would ask you to do less typing. Since the dates are in character, I extracted year using `substr()`. If you have a date object, you need to do something else. Once you have year, you group the data with it and calculate how many schools exist for each type of school using `count()`. This part is the equivalent of your `aggregate()` code. Then, Convert the output to a wide-format data with `spread()` and did the rest of the calculation as you demonstrated in your codes. The final output seems different from what you have in your question, but my outcome was identical to one that I obtained by running your codes. I hope this will help you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)

# Get the necessary data
foo <- read_xls("pubschls.xls") %>%
       select(NCESDist, CDSCode, OpenDate, ClosedDate, Charter) %>%
       filter(NCESDist == "0622710" & (!Charter %in% NA))


mutate(foo, group = paste(Charter, as.numeric(is.na(ClosedDate)), sep = "_"),
       year = substr(OpenDate, star = nchar(OpenDate) - 3, stop = nchar(OpenDate))) %>%
count(year, group) %>%
spread(key = group, value = n, fill = 0) %>%
mutate(net_chart = Y_1 - Y_0,
       net_pub = N_1 - N_0,
       cum_chart = cumsum(net_chart),
       cum_pub = cumsum(net_pub),
       total = cum_chart + cum_pub,
       pen_rate = cum_chart / total)

# A part of the outcome
#    year N_0 N_1 Y_0 Y_1 net_chart net_pub cum_chart cum_pub total   pen_rate
#1   1866   0   1   0   0         0       1         0       1     1 0.00000000
#2   1873   0   1   0   0         0       1         0       2     2 0.00000000
#3   1878   0   1   0   0         0       1         0       3     3 0.00000000
#4   1881   0   1   0   0         0       1         0       4     4 0.00000000
#5   1882   0   2   0   0         0       2         0       6     6 0.00000000
#110 2007   0   2  15   9        -6       2        87     393   480 0.18125000
#111 2008   2   8   9  15         6       6        93     399   492 0.18902439
#112 2009   1   9   4  15        11       8       104     407   511 0.20352250
#113 2010   5  26   5  21        16      21       120     428   548 0.21897810
#114 2011   2  16   2  18        16      14       136     442   578 0.23529412
#115 2012   2  27   3   7         4      25       140     467   607 0.23064250
#116 2013   1   5   1  19        18       4       158     471   629 0.25119237
#117 2014   1   3   1  18        17       2       175     473   648 0.27006173
#118 2015   0   0   2  18        16       0       191     473   664 0.28765060
#119 2016   0   3   0   8         8       3       199     476   675 0.29481481
#120 2017   0   5   0   9         9       5       208     481   689 0.30188679
```

Comment: @Francisco Pleasure to help you. :)